# JavaFX select text from second column does not matter where in row is clicked

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I have a little problem I need to select exactly one column(cell) of row independently where I click in row.

For example I have 3 column table, I click on first column but I need text of second column every time.

Is there any way I can do this. In swing there were indexes for rows and columns but i can't find anything like that in JavaFX.

My code for double click selection is:

```
@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent click) {
    if (click.getClickCount() == 2) {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        TablePosition pos = searchResult.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0);
        int row = pos.getRow();
        int col = pos.getColumn();
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        TableColumn column = pos.getTableColumn();
        String val = column.getCellData(row).toString();
        System.out.println("Selected Value, " + val + ", Column: " + col + ", Row: " + row);
        try {
            if (button1.isSelected()) {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /select," + val);
            } else {
                if (button2.isSelected()) {
                    File file = new File(val);
                    Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks you for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you actually want to select the cell**

You can set the [cellSelectionEnabledProperty of the selection model of your table view](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableSelectionModel.html#cellSelectionEnabledProperty) to `true`.

You can listen to the change of the [focused cell property of the focus model of your table view](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.TableViewFocusModel.html#focusedCellProperty).

Then in the change listener you can select any [TableColumn](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html) what you want in the same row.

**Example:**

```
// Enable cell selection
tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

// On focused property change
tableView.getFocusModel().focusedCellProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TablePosition>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TablePosition> arg0, TablePosition arg1, TablePosition arg2) {
        // Select TableColumn "col2" in the same row
        tableView.getSelectionModel().select(arg2.getRow(), col2);

    }
});
```

This will produce a tableview which selects the cell in the desired column independently which cell is selected in the row.

**If you just want to get the value of a cell on row selection**

```
// Just row selection
tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(false);

tableView.getFocusModel().focusedCellProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TablePosition>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TablePosition> arg0, TablePosition arg1, TablePosition arg2) {
        // Get the data from the desired cell (tableview displays Data objects)
        Data item = tableView.getItems().get(arg2.getRow());
        String data = (String) col2.getCellObservableValue(item).getValue();
        System.out.println(data);
    }
});
```

This example gets and prints the value from the desired column independently which column is selected.

Comment: Thanks you very much

Answer (score 2):

Register the mouse listener with the table row, using a row factory:

```
TableView<MyDataType> tableView = ... ;

tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<MyDataType> row = new TableRow<>();
    row.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
            MyDataType rowData = row.getItem();
            if (rowData != null) {
                // get value displayed in second column from rowData...
                // and process it however you need
            }
        }
    });
    return row ;
});
```